# .NET Core API Call with JSON Payload and File

Tags: json, api, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am really stuck on something for the past couple of days.  I have reviewed about all the code samples I can find and I am not sure if this is even possible.

We are making an API call to a remote server.  We are passing in a JSON payload and this works fine by itself.  But we now want to add a file to the API call.  Th fil is uploaded from a form.

If I do the API call for the file (by itself) it seems to be making it to the API.  As stated, the JSON payload works by itself as well.  But I cannot get both of them to go.

Here is the API we are calling where Dealership is a model

```
    public HttpResponseMessage CreateDealership(Dealership dealership)
    {

    }
```

Here is the call (from within a class file) to the API with just JSON.  Again, this works fine:

```
    var client = new HttpClient(GetClientHandler()); //client with NTML credentials
    var apidata = FormatUserAPIData(); //returns API data
    var apicall = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:1234/api/leap/createdealership", apidata);
    if (apicall.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        return "true";
    }
```

And here is the version of the call (from within a class file) that sends just the file in multipartdata.  The file is uploaded by the user.  Again, the file seems to make it there as the incoming file count is, in fact, 1:

```
        var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();

        var filestream = new FileStream(path + @"\" + filename, FileMode.Open);
        var filename = resumefilename;
        content.Add(new StreamContent(filestream), "file", filename);

        var client = new HttpClient(GetClientHandler()); //client with NTML credentials

        var apicall = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:1234/api/leap/createdealership", content);
        if (apicall.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return "true";
        }
```

But I am unable to combine both it seems.  I have tried adding this to the multipart in the above example but it is never recognized as a JSON payload.  Thus, it causes an error because the Dealership model is empty

```
content.Add(apidata, "apidata");
```

Am I making any sense here?  Can this be done?  How to I send a JSON payload and also include a multipart file?

Answer (score 0):

**`MultipartFormDataContent`**, which acts like a form. So you need to pass the value like a form.

Use `content.Add(new StringContent("value"), "key")`

```
        string filePath = @"path\1.txt";
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();

        var filestream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
        var filename = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
       
        content.Add(new StreamContent(filestream), "file", filename);

        //here is the other data in form
        content.Add(new StringContent("my-content"), "Property");

        var response = await client.PostAsync("https://localhost:port/val/createdealership/", content);
```

In action, add `[FromForm]`. Then, the other data can be passed here.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Karney.  I was able to figure this out.  I was very close but seemed to be getting off course with all the pseudocode examples out there.  I am going to post below what worked if it helps someone else.  This is for a .NET Core 5 application that is calling an API with .NET Core on Framework 4.5

The API POST method.  Dealership has model fields of DealerName, DealerAddress, DealerCity used in the API call.

```
 [HttpPost]
 public HttpResponseMessage CreateDealership(Dealership dealership)
 {  

 }
```

The code that calls the API.  This will populate the Dealership model and also post the file to the API so you can save it on that system.

```
    string filePath = @"path\1.txt";
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();

    var filestream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
    var filename = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
   
    content.Add(new StreamContent(filestream), "file", filename);

    //Where these would be values from the form or values from a database query to be 
    //sent to the API
    string dealername = "Some Car Dealership";
    string dealeraddress = "123 Main St.";
    string dealercity = "Somewhere";

    content.Add(new StringContent(dealername, "DealerName");
    content.Add(new StringContent(dealeraddress, "DealerAddress");
    content.Add(new StringContent(dealercity, "DealerCity");

    var response = await 

    client.PostAsync("https://localhost:port/val/createdealership/", content);
```